# How to fix 8000 port is already in use django runserver problem?

Tags: python, django, django-manage.py

I am trying to run Django project in ubuntu 20.04 LTS but it shows 8000 port already in use.

I can run using> python manage.py runserver 8080

But I want to free my 8000 port

How can I do that?

```
(env) amol@amol-Ideapad-320:~/My Code/Python/ecommerse-models/ecomm$ python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 03, 2022 - 15:12:45
Django version 4.1, using settings 'ecomm.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Error: That port is already in use.
```

Comment: Find the ID of processing using the port 8000 `lsof -i:8000` and kill it using `kill -9 <process ID>`

Comment: it shows nothing